# Whats the best way to sort 3D objects in a game for speed and to avoid redundant open gl es 2 calls

Tags: iphone, ios, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

EDIT - To help clarify the question up top.. I guess I'm looking for which sorting would perform better: sorting by program or sorting by textures?  Will it matter?  All my objects are in similar z space and all are stored in the same VBO.  And if I don't switch shaders via glUseProgram do I have to re-set attributes for each object?

Original Post:

This is sort of a 2-part question. I'm trying to figure out how best to sort my 3d objects before drawing them, and what open gl calls have to be done for each glDrawElements and which ones can be done once per screen refresh (or even just once).  The purpose is of course for speed.  For my game let's assume that z front to back isn't much of an issue (most objects are at the same z).  So I won't be sorting for z other than to do all objects with transparency last.

Of course I don't want the sorting process to take longer than rendering unsorted.

Part 2 is which open gl calls have to be used per glDrawElements and which ones can be done only when the information changes?  And does presentRenderbuffer wipe certain things out so that you have to re-call them.

Most opengl 2 demos do every call for every object.  Actually most demos only draw one object.  So in an 3d engine (like I'm writing) I want to avoid unnecessary redundant calls.

This is the order I was doing it (unsorted, unoptimized):

```
glUseProgram(glPrograms[useProgram]);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

Loop through objects {

   Do all matrix calcs

   Set Uniforms (matrix, camera pos, light pos, light colors, material properties)

   Activate Textures.. (x2)
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
   glUniform1i(glUniforms[useProgram][U_textureSampler], 0);

   Bind VBOs
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelVertVBO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelIndVBO);

   Set Attributes (vertexpos, texcoord, norm, tan, bitan)

   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, models[modelToUse].indSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *) (models[modelToUse].indOffset * sizeof(GLuint)));
}
```

Of course that only worked when all objects used the same shader/program.  In practice they won't.

3D objects are in an array with all the properties for each object: model id, shader id, texture ids, position, etc.  So my idea was to do a fast simple sort to stack similar objects' index numbers in other arrays.  Then draw the items in each of those arrays.  I could sort by 3d model (object type), texture, or by shader.  Many models share the same texture.  Many models share the same shader.  At this point I have 3 shaders.  ALL OBJECTS share a single VBO.

Can I do it like this?

```
Bind the VBO - since all objects use the same one
Loop through object types {
   If shader hasn't changed
      glUseProgram
      Set Attributes
   If texture hasn't changed
      glActiveTexture(s) - based on which program is active
   Loop through objects of that type {
      Do matrix calcs
      Set Uniforms - based on which program is active
      glDrawElements
   }
}
```

EDIT - To be clear - I'm still drawing all objects, just in a different order to combine uses of shaders and/or textures so as to avoid binding and then rebinding again within one 'frame' of the game.

I'm currently getting a crash on a glDrawElements on the 2nd refresh, but I think that will be easy to find.  I only include this fact because it leads me to think that binding a texture might not carry over to a second frame (or presentBuffers).

Is it going to be faster to avoid changing the shader, or changing the texture?  Will attributes, the vbo, and the textures stay active across multiple glDrawElement calls?  Across multiple presentBuffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

First some context.  I currently have 3 shaders and expect I'll end up with no more than 4 or 5.  Example I have a bump map shader that uses a base and normal texture.  I also have a shader that doesn't use a base texture and instead uses a solid color for the object but does still have a normal texture.  Then I have the opposite, a flat lighting simple shader that uses a base texture only.

I have many different 3d models but all use the same VBO.  And some 3d models use the same textures as others.

So in the definition of a 3d object I added a renderSort property that I can preset knowing what shader program it uses and what texture(s) it needs.

Then as I update objects and determine if they need to be drawn on screen, I also do a one pass simple sort on them based on the renderSort property of their 3d object type... I just toss the array index of the object in a 'bucket' array.  I don't see having more than 10 of these buckets.

After the update and quick-sort I render.

The render iterates through the buckets, and inside that through the objects in each bucket. Inside the inner loop I check to see if the program has changed since the last object, and do a glUseProgram if it's changed.  Same with textures.. I only bind them if they're not currently bound.  Then update all the other uniforms and do the glDrawElements.

The previous way.. unsorted.. if there were 1000 objects it would call glUseProgram, bind the textures, bind the vbo, set all the attributes.. 1000 times.

Now.. it only changes these things when it needs to.. if it needs to 1000 times it will still do it 1000 times.  But with the bucket sort it should only need to do it once per bucket. This way I prioritize drawing properly even if they're not sorted properly.

Here's the code:

Sorting...

```
if (drawThisOne) {
        // if an object needs to be drawn - toss it in a sort bucket.
        // each itemType has a predetermined bucket number so that objects will be grouped into rough program and texture groups
        int itemTypeID = allObjects[objectIndex].itemType;
        int bucket = itemTypes[itemTypeID].renderSort;

        sorted3dObjects[bucket][sorted3Counts[bucket]]=objectIndex;
        // increment the count for that bucket
        sorted3Counts[bucket]++;
}
```

Rendering...

```
// only do these once per cycle as all objects are in the same VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelVertVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelIndVBO);

for (int bucket=0; bucket<10; bucket++) {
    // does this bucket have anything in it?
    if (sorted3Counts[bucket]>0) {
        // if so itterate though items in that bucket
        for (int thisObject=0; thisObject < sorted3Counts[bucket]; thisObject++) {
            // get the object index for this object in this bucket
            int objectIndex = sorted3dObjects[bucket][thisObject];
            int itemTypeID = candyPieces[objectIndex].pieceType;

            int modelToUse = itemTypes[itemTypeID].model;

            // switching to psudocode...

            GLuint useProgram = itemTypes[itemTypeID].shader;
            if (Program Changed or is not set) {
                glUseProgram(glPrograms[useProgram]);
                glDisable(GL_BLEND);
                glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
                currentProgram=useProgram;

                USE glVertexAttribPointer to set all attributes
            }

            // based on which program is active set textures and program specific uniforms
            switch (useProgram) { ....
                if (Texture Changed or is not set) {
                     glActiveTexture(s)
                }
            }

            Matrix Calculations
            glUniform - to set unforms

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, models[modelToUse].indSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *) (models[modelToUse].indOffset * sizeof(GLuint)));
          }}}
```